# How to use std::allocator_traits::construct to create struct object from function parameters?

Tags: c++, function, struct, arguments, parameter-passing

I have a struct defined as:

```
struct Foo
{
    double x;
    double y;
};
```

I have a function which takes this struct as a parameter:

```
void doSomethingWithFoo(Foo foo);
```

I'd also like to use this function by passing the struct members directly:

```
void doSomethingWithFoo(double x, double y);
```

Is there a way using `std::allocator_traits::construct` or any other way to be able to that without explicitly defining the second function?

Comment: it is unclear why you think you need `std::allocator_traits`. The question is really just: "How to enable calling `void doSomethingWithFoo(Foo foo);` as `doSomethingWithFoo(x,y);`", right?

Comment: The documentation for `vector::emplace` mentions that "The element is constructed in-place by calling allocator_traits::construct with args forwarded.
"

Comment: ..but there is no vector in your code

Comment: The documentation for `std::vector::emplace` mentions this for people who want to supply their own allocators. But allocators are not used specifically to construct objects from arguments but to manage memory allocations (as the name implies). If you don't want to control memory allocation, you won't need allocators. Basically, `std::vector::emplace` involves doing X and Y, the documentation mentions Y (so you ask about Y) but the aspect that you actually want/need is X. See also [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what your real problem involves? Do you have many different classes (you only show one) that this should work with? Or does `Foo` have many constructors? If neither is the case, what do you hope to gain from doing this over just calling `doSomethingWithFoo({x, y});`?

Comment: Mine is a simple case. So `doSomethingWithFoo({x, y})` should work for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just do this directly: `doSomethingWithFoo({ 1, 2 });`. The compiler knows that `doSomethingWithFoo` takes a `Foo` type, so it looks for a conversion from what you give it (`int, int`) to `Foo`. As a simple "plain old data" (POD) type, then the constructor from the initializer list is implicit, and it just works.

```
struct Foo
{
    double x;
    double y;
};

void doSomethingWithFoo(Foo foo)
{
    std::cout << foo.x << ", " << foo.y << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    doSomethingWithFoo({ 1, 2 });

    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
1, 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Considering that `Foo` is a simple POD-type, you can create an instance of it as `Foo{x, y}`.

Then you could just make an overload that calls the first version of the function:

```
inline void doSomethingWithFoo(double x, double y)
{
    doSomethingWithFoo(Foo{x, y});
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I do currently. I was wondering if there's a way without explicitly overloading the function.  The documentation for `vector::emplace` mentions that "The element is constructed in-place by calling allocator_traits::construct with args forwarded". I was wondering if I could use this someway to avoid the overload definition

Comment: @locke14 Using allocators for this is just overkill. It can be done but requires more work and more code. Is there a *specific* reason you want to use allocators?

Comment: `doSomethingWithFoo({x, y})` should work well enough in my case